# Assumptions are not being applied to integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am trying to use assumptions to simplify an integral, but I can't seem to get the assumptions to apply themselves. Here is the code I am using:

[image: my code]

Note the expressions in the assumption can be found in the answer.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a proper way of using assumptions? I read through the *Mathematica* tutorial for [assumptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingAssumptions.html) but that seems to have confused me more.

Comment: Could you please include yor code in the answer - with all preliminary function and variable defenitions.

Comment: Apsrt from the tutorial on Assumptions you probably should also read its [dedicated documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assumptions.html). There, under the heading "More information" (v8) or "Details" (v9) you can find: "The assumptions can be equations, inequalities, or domain specifications, or lists or logical combinations of these." So: no `Rule`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assumptions need to be quantified equations or inequalities, so replace your rules with equations.  I'm guessing `Integrate` probably won't do too much with these, either, so attempt to use `FullSimplify` on the results with your new assumptions.